# spring-integration: dispatch queued messages to selective consumer

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have a spring integration flow which produces messages that should be kept around waiting for an appropriate consumer to come along and consume them.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow messagesPerCustomerFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.
            from(WebFlux.inboundChannelAdapter("/messages/{customer}")
                    .requestMapping(r -> r
                            .methods(HttpMethod.POST)
                    )
                    .requestPayloadType(JsonNode.class)
                    .headerExpression("customer", "#pathVariables.customer")
            )
            .channel(messagesPerCustomerQueue()) 
            .get();
}

@Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
public PollerSpec poller() {
    return Pollers.fixedRate(100);
}

@Bean
public QueueChannel messagesPerCustomerQueue() {
    return MessageChannels.queue()
            .get();
}
```

The messages in the queue should be delivered as server-sent events via http as shown below.

The PublisherSubscription is just a holder for the Publisher and the IntegrationFlowRegistration, the latter is used to destroy the dynamically created flow when it is no longer needed (note that the incoming message for the GET has no content, which is not handled properly ATM by the Webflux integration, hence a small workaround is necessary to get access to the path variable shoved to the `customer` header):

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow eventMessagesPerCustomer() {
    return IntegrationFlows
       .from(WebFlux.inboundGateway("/events/{customer}")
            .requestMapping(m -> m.produces(TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE))
            .headerExpression("customer", "#pathVariables.customer")
            .payloadExpression("''") // neeeded to make handle((p,h) work
       )
       .log()
       .handle((p, h) -> {
           String customer = h.get("customer").toString();
           PublisherSubscription<JsonNode> publisherSubscription =
               subscribeToMessagesPerCustomer(customer);
           return Flux.from(publisherSubscription.getPublisher())
                   .map(Message::getPayload)
                   .doFinally(signalType ->
                      publisherSubscription.unsubscribe());
       })
       .get();
}
```

The above request for server-sent events dynamically registers a flow which subscribes to the queue channel on demand with a [selective consumer](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/MessageSelector.html) realized by a filter with `throwExceptionOnRejection(true)`. Following the spec for [Message Handler chain](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#chain-introduction) that should ensure that the message is offered to all consumers until one accepts it.

```
public PublisherSubscription<JsonNode> subscribeToMessagesPerCustomer(String customer) {
    IntegrationFlowBuilder flow = IntegrationFlows.from(messagesPerCustomerQueue())
            .filter("headers.customer=='" + customer + "'",
                    filterEndpointSpec -> filterEndpointSpec.throwExceptionOnRejection(true));
    Publisher<Message<JsonNode>> messagePublisher = flow.toReactivePublisher();

    IntegrationFlowRegistration registration = integrationFlowContext.registration(flow.get())
            .register();

    return new PublisherSubscription<>(messagePublisher, registration);
}
```

This construct works in principle, but with the following issues:

- Messages sent to the queue while there are no subscribers at all lead to a `MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application.messagesPerCustomerQueue'`
- Messages sent to the queue while no matching subscriber is present yet lead to an `AggregateMessageDeliveryException: All attempts to deliver Message to MessageHandlers failed`.

What I want is that the message remains in the queue and is repeatedly offered to all subscribers until it is either consumed or expires (a proper selective consumer). How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> note that the incoming message for the GET has no content, which is not handled properly ATM by the Webflux integration

I don't understand this concern.

The `WebFluxInboundEndpoint` works with this algorithm:

```
if (isReadable(request)) {
   ...
else {
    return (Mono<T>) Mono.just(exchange.getRequest().getQueryParams());
}
```

Where `GET` method really goes to the `else` branch. And the `payload` of the message to send is a `MultiValueMap`. And also we recently fixed with you the problem for the `POST`, which is released already as well in version `5.0.5`: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4462

> Dispatcher has no subscribers

Can't happen on the `QueueChannel` in principle. There is no any dispatcher on there at all. It is just queue and sender *offers* message to be stored. You are missing something else to share with us. But let's call things with its own names: the `messagesPerCustomerQueue` is not a `QueueChannel` in your application.

**UPDATE**

Regarding:

> What I want is that the message remains in the queue and is repeatedly offered to all subscribers until it is either consumed or expires (a proper selective consumer)

Only what we see is a `PollableJmsChannel` based on the embedded ActiveMQ to honor TTL for messages. As a consumer of this queue you should have a `PublishSubscribeChannel` with the `setMinSubscribers(1)` to make `MessagingTemplate` to throw a `MessageDeliveryException` when there is no subscribers yet. This way a JMS transaction will be rolled back and message will return to the queue for the next polling cycle.

The problem with in-memory `QueueChannel` that there is no transactional redelivery and message once polled from that queue is going to be lost.

Another option is similar to JMS (transactional) is a `JdbcChannelMessageStore` for the `QueueChannel`. Although this way we don't have a TTL functionality...

Comment: As you say, the payload of the GET message becomes an empty multivalue map. But that has a funny effect: the payload rather than the header gets copied into `args[1]` for `handle()` in line 103/104 of `LambdaMessageProcessor`, so that both p and h contain the empty map. I'll open a Jira issue for further discussion about that.

Concerning the queue: it is in fact a queue channel with poller, I have added the bean configuration above. I can commit the sample into https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/pull/225

Comment: Oh! That's interesting... Yes, please, raise a JIRA on the matter.

Comment: Please, take a look into my UPDATE in the answer.

Comment: Thank you for JIRA! Will take a look later. Please, pay attention to the UPDATE in my answer for your original issue